# Is it possible to convert crontab format to an interval format in seconds

Tags: cron

I have 4 types of cron jobs that run at regular intervals. Is it possible to convert the cron format into an interval format?

```
cron       | interval
----------------------
* * * * *  | 60 seconds
0 * * * *  | 3600 seconds
30 * * * * | 3600 seconds
0 0 * * *  | 86400 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to convert the CRON string into a human-readable format or just into seconds?

If the former, I found a few options depending on your programming language of choice (I'm sure there are more out there for other languages):

- [cron-expression-descriptor for C#](https://github.com/bradymholt/cron-expression-descriptor)
- [cRonstrue for Javascript/Typescript](https://github.com/bradymholt/cRonstrue)
- [cron-parser for Java](https://github.com/grahamar/cron-parser)

Comment: I'm looking to convert it into seconds.

Answer (score 0):

the [fugit](https://github.com/floraison/fugit) gem does exactly what I need

```
require 'fugit'
c = Fugit::Cron.parse('0 0 * * *')
p c.rough_frequency

=> 86400
```